# Feynman diagrams and gluon collisions/interactions?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, conservation-laws, standard-model, feynman-diagrams

We have been given this question which essentially asks us to draw the lowest order Feynman diagrams for various processes. One of them is:

$$
g + g \rightarrow \bar{t}+t
$$

Now, I am not an expert in particle physics or Feynman diagrams by any stretch of the imagination but isn't this not even possible in the standard model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are possible. Hope this helps. 
Also here is a link for the rules and understanding how to construct them.
http://www.quantumdiaries.org/2010/02/14/lets-draw-feynman-diagams/

This may help in your thinking : Real or Virtual 
Where does the redundancy in Feynman diagrams come from? In a nutshell: virtual particles. Anyone looking at a Feynman diagram might get the impression that the diagram is telling a story of particles interacting. But the internal lines in Feynman diagrams – the ones tracing “particles” that are neither input nor output – do not actually represent physical particles. Instead, they are said to represent virtual particles – particles whose momenta are physically impossible.

[image]

Comment: Could you add a citation for the two diagrams you have given. I'm not sure how two gluons can interact to create on gluon and then split into a quark anti-quark pair?

Comment: What is the coupling between the two gluons in the bottom diagram? Where does that come from and what does it represent?

Comment: Apologies for asking yet another question, but can this gluon-gluon interacting lead to the production of any quark anti-quark production?